# R read_excel or readxl Multiple Files with Multiple Sheets - Bind

Tags: r, excel, tidyverse, readxl

I have a directory full of .xlsx files. They all have multiple sheets. I want to extract the same sheet from all of the files and append them into a tibble.

I have found numerous solutions for extracting multiple sheets from a single Excel file; however, not a single sheet from multiple files.

I have tried:

```r
    paths = as.tibble(list.files("data/BAH", pattern = ".xlsx", full.names = TRUE, all.files = FALSE))

    test <- paths %>% read_xlsx(sheet = "Portal", col_names = TRUE)
```

I know the "paths" variable contains all of my file names with path. However, I am not sure how to iterate through each file name appending just the specific sheet = "Portal" to a csv file.

The error is:

```
Error: path must be a string
```

I have tried to pass in paths as a vector, as a tibble, and tried sub-scripting it as well. All fails.

So, in summary. I have a directory of xlsx files and I need to extract a single sheet from each one and append it to a csv file. I have tried using purrr with some map functions but also could not get it to work.

My goal was to use the Tidy way.

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `lapply()` or `map()`. Try

```
test <- lapply(paths, read_xlsx, sheet = "Portal", col_names = TRUE)
```

or

```
library(purrr)
test <- map_dfr(paths, read_xlsx, sheet = "Portal", col_names = TRUE)
```

You can then bind the dataframes with

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% bind_rows()
```

Comment: Your answer worked. Do you know a way to add a column with the file name string added?

Comment: how do you do this if you are passing a table to map_dfr with a column for the path and a column for the sheet?  When I do map_dfr(tibble_df, ~read_excel(path = tibble_df$path, sheet = tibble_df$sheet)) I get  Error in tibble_df$path : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)    
library(readxl)
library(fs)

# Get all files
xlsx_files <- fs::dir_ls("data/BAH", regexp = "\\.xlsx$")

paths = as_tibble(list.files("data/BAH", pattern = ".xlsx", full.names = TRUE, all.files = FALSE))


#portal_tabs <- map_dfr(paths, read_xlsx, sheet = "Portal", col_names = TRUE)
portal_tabs <- map_dfr(xlsx_files, read_xlsx, sheet = "Portal", col_names = TRUE, .id = 'source')
```