# How to import & bind multiple excel with multiple tabs (Names common)

Tags: r, import, data-binding, readxl

I want to import multiple excel files. Each file contains 3 tabs with same name with other files. Eg. Studentname,studentdivision, studentmarks.

I want to import all files and bind them in unique tabs and export one file with these 3 tabs data

Need help
I tried but it won't work

Answer (score 0):

There is [R read_excel or readxl Multiple Files with Multiple Sheets - Bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56858190/r-read-excel-or-readxl-multiple-files-with-multiple-sheets-bind), but it only contains information on how to read a single sheet from multiple files and combine the results to one data frame.

This answer is extending that approach to a situation with multiple different sheets across files, resulting in multiple dataframes.

**First** of all, set your working directory to the folder with the files.

**Second** step: List all `.xlsx` files in that folder

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern = "*.xlsx", full.names = TRUE)
```

**Third** step: create empty list

```
df <- list()
```

**Fourth** step: run a `for` loop to:

- read in all sheets number `i` across all files (using `lapply()`)
- combine all sheets number `i` with `rbind()`
- store the results in a previously created empty list (`df`)

*Note*: all column names must be the same in the same sheets, otherwise `rbind()` wont work. And sheet order has to be similar across all files.

```
for (i in 1:3) {
  df_list <- lapply(filenames, readxl::read_excel, sheet = i)
  df[[i]] <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
}
```

Now you have one data frame per sheet, and all are stored inside a list.

Either you work with that, or you unlist them to your environment as described here: [Unlist a list of dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697239/unlist-a-list-of-dataframes)